# How to update ng-repeat list after http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to update my ng-repeat list after I do PUT request. Service works fine.

controller.js

```
teamData.updateTeam(team.id, teamObj, function(res) {
                        console.log('Success');
                    });
```

service.js

```
teamService.updateTeam = function(teamId, param, callback) {
          var req = {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/team' + teamId,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'data': param
          };
          return $http(req).then(function(res){
            callback(res);
          }, function(err){
            callback(err);
          });
        };
```

teamRoute.js

```
app.put('/team/:id', function(request, response) {
    var options = {
        host: reqParam.hostFramework,
        path: reqParam.path + '/team/' + request.params.id,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'token': reqParam.token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(request.body))
        }
    };
    var resString = '';
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            resString += d;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            response.send(resString);
        });
    });
    req.write(JSON.stringify(request.body));
    req.end();
});
```

team.html

```
<div ng-repeat="team in teamData">
    <h2>{{team.name}}</h2>
    ....
</div>
```

My goal is to update the ng-repeat list just after PUT request is made (no page refresh). How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should just be able to push whatever you want into what you're repeating before/after/during your request.

Comment: Where is the `ngRepeat` part? How do you update the items after the request? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Added teamRoute.js and team.html files

Answer (score 2):

Assign it back to the model.  For example if your ng-repeat was on $scope.item then:

```
 return $http(req).then(function(res){
        callback(res);
        $scope.item = res
      }, function(err){
        callback(err);
      });
```

Comment: Breaks the binding? How? This is exactly how binding works.

Comment: It does not update my team.html. I have to reload page to see changes